# Criteria groupProperty() is not working while retrieving entity object list

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria, hibernate-criteria

In hibernate criteria while retrieving the entity object list i am getting only `groupProperty("property")` column list how to solve this problem any suggestions will be appreciated.Here is my code

```
    Session session=sessionFactory.openSession();
    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Company.class);
    criteria.setProjection(Projections.groupProperty("companyName"));
    List<Company_Info> list=criteria.list();
    session.close();
    return list;
```

Here i am trying to get the `Company.class` object but i am getting the `companyName` list finally it is resulting `classCastException`

Comment: what is the point of grouping if there is no aggregate?

Comment: @MaciejKowalski thanks for your reply, here i want to get the entire `Company` Object by grouping the `companyName` it is working fine in HQL but not in criteria hope you did understood.